# Running a Xcode Console application in Background

Tags: swift, xcode, shell, terminal

I have a Console app that is created in **Xcode** Which has few shell scripts to fetch mac values like battery percentage, disk space, and Partition status. All these values will be stored in a log file.

How to run the console app in the background **every 15 mins**?

One solution is by using a **Corn Job** to schedule and execute but I need some other solutions to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained what cron isn't appropriate for you, but the modern OS X way is to use launchd

https://www.launchd.info